# Rewriting Pandas script using Python3 standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here's the script written in Pandas which I have to rewrite using the standard library:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 1 :
        print('usage: python by_continent.py')
        sys.exit(1)

    gap = pd.read_csv('gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')
    means = gap.groupby('continent').mean()
    parts = means[['lifeExp', 'gdpPercap']]
    print( parts )
```

Input looks like:

```
country continent   year    lifeExp pop gdpPercap
Zambia  Africa  2002    39.193  10595811    1071.613938 
Zambia  Africa  2007    42.384  11746035    1271.211593 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1952    48.451  3080907 406.8841148 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1957    50.469  3646340 518.7642681 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1962    52.358  4277736 527.2721818 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1967    53.995  4995432 569.7950712 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1972    55.635  5861135 799.3621758 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1977    57.674  6642107 685.5876821 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1982    60.363  7636524 788.8550411 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1987    62.351  9216418 706.1573059 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1992    60.377  10704340    693.4207856 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1997    46.809  11404948    792.4499603 
Zimbabwe    Africa  2002    39.989  11926563    672.0386227 
Zimbabwe    Africa  2007    43.487  12311143    469.7092981 
Argentina   Americas    1952    62.485  17876956    5911.315053 
Argentina   Americas    1957    64.399  19610538    6856.856212 
Argentina   Americas    1962    65.142  21283783    7133.166023 
Argentina   Americas    1967    65.634  22934225    8052.953021 
Argentina   Americas    1972    67.065  24779799    9443.038526 
Argentina   Americas    1977    68.481  26983828    10079.02674
```

Here's what the output should be:

```
             lifeExp     gdpPercap
continent
Africa     48.865330   2193.754578
Americas   64.658737   7136.110356
Asia       60.064903   7902.150428
Europe     71.903686  14469.475533
Oceania    74.326208  18621.609223
```

I'm stuck. I can get as far as parsing the code with the csv module but can't get much further. Here's my code:

```
import sys 
import csv

with open('gapminder.tsv', 'r') as gap:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(gap, delimiter="\t")
    lst = list(csv_reader)

    for row in lst: 
        if row [1] == 'Africa': 
            pop = []
            pop.append(row[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the groupby you could just use a dictionary which you fill the keys with programmatically and the values start null and end with a list of 3-tuples; it'd have the column name, the type of calculation and the value that you should be returning for the given combination.

There may be prettier and more elegant ways but this should work.

Edit: wait no they'd be 2-tuples since you've already specified the column (I meant continent) name.  I think I'm still half asleep.

You could also just make an n-dimensional list (matrix) that holds all the relevant values.  That'd be the sensible way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, i'll start poking around using that method.

Answer (score 0):

The below should get you started (forgive the lazy variable naming).  The main idea is to leverage the existing `groupby` from itertools to aggregate by whatever field you want, and then from those groupings pull out the relevant field you want to average by collecting the results into a dictionary.

P.S. - hopefully this isn't your homework, because that's just lazy :)

```
stuff = """country continent   year    lifeExp pop gdpPercap
Zambia  Africa  2002    39.193  10595811    1071.613938 
Zambia  Africa  2007    42.384  11746035    1271.211593 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1952    48.451  3080907 406.8841148 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1957    50.469  3646340 518.7642681 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1962    52.358  4277736 527.2721818 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1967    53.995  4995432 569.7950712 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1972    55.635  5861135 799.3621758 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1977    57.674  6642107 685.5876821 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1982    60.363  7636524 788.8550411 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1987    62.351  9216418 706.1573059 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1992    60.377  10704340    693.4207856 
Zimbabwe    Africa  1997    46.809  11404948    792.4499603 
Zimbabwe    Africa  2002    39.989  11926563    672.0386227 
Zimbabwe    Africa  2007    43.487  12311143    469.7092981 
Argentina   Americas    1952    62.485  17876956    5911.315053 
Argentina   Americas    1957    64.399  19610538    6856.856212 
Argentina   Americas    1962    65.142  21283783    7133.166023 
Argentina   Americas    1967    65.634  22934225    8052.953021 
Argentina   Americas    1972    67.065  24779799    9443.038526 
Argentina   Americas    1977    68.481  26983828    10079.02674""".strip().splitlines()

import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

stuff = [line.split() for line in stuff]
headers, *records = stuff
labeled_records = [dict(zip(headers,line)) for line in records]

#group by continent
grouped = itertools.groupby(labeled_records,lambda x: x['continent'])
results = defaultdict(list)

# for other categories, just change 'lifeExp' to the column you want 
for k,v in grouped:
    for d in v:
        results[k].append(float(d['lifeExp']))

# average collected results     
for k,v in results.items():
    print(k,'\t',sum(v)/len(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to spoil the fun of calculating the solutions but you could convert this to a a list of dictionaries and that would make the data easier to manage. To do so, you need to split all the sublists, the we to zip each sublist with its own list from row 1 those will be our keys, then we can zip those sublist with the keys. After that we use a `dict()` constructor to create our list of dictionaries.

With this you can do things like `for i in res: print(i['country']` etc etc, pull dictionaries from the list that only are of a certain country and so forth.

```
import csv
import pprint

with open('gapminder.tsv', 'r') as gap:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(gap, delimiter="\t")
    lst = list(csv_reader)

lst = [i[0].split() for i in lst]
prep = zip([lst[0]]*len(lst[1:]), lst[1:])
prep = [(zip(i[0], i[1])) for i in prep]
res = [dict([j for j in i]) for i in prep]
pprint.pprint(res)
```

> ```
> [{'continent': 'Africa',
>   'country': 'Zambia',
>   'gdpPercap': '1071.613938',
>   'lifeExp': '39.193',
>   'pop': '10595811',
>   'year': '2002'},
>  {'continent': 'Africa',
>   'country': 'Zambia',
>   'gdpPercap': '1271.211593',
>   'lifeExp': '42.384',
>   'pop': '11746035',
>   'year': '2007'},
> ...
> ```